# Python: Need to find beginning of each trial in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, valueerror

I have a pandas dataframe of an experiment with multiple trials. The trials are numbered 1-12 and there are multiple rows per trial. I would like to make a column of 1s and 0s where 1 indicates where a trial begins. This is the code I have:

```
for i in df['Trial Start']:
if df.groupby('Trial Number').head(1):
    i = 1
else:
    i = 0
```

I am getting the error 'ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all'

I know why I'm getting this error, but I also know there's definitely a better way to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide sample of data you are processing

Comment: have one example?

Comment: Is the dataframe sorted by "trial no"? If it is, there's the `shift` command, where you can compare a row to the following or previous row and you can set a value of "1" wherever those values are different

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform()` to get this done.

```
    dict = {'Trial Number': [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,6]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
    df['Trial Start'] = df.groupby('Trial Number')['Trial Number']
           .transform(lambda x: [1]+[0]*(len(x)-1))
    print(df)

    Trial Number  Trial Start
0              1            1
1              1            0
2              1            0
3              1            0
4              2            1
5              2            0
6              3            1
7              3            0
8              3            0
9              3            0
10             4            1
11             4            0
12             4            0
13             4            0
14             5            1
15             6            1
```

In this example, the function passed to `transform()` is in turn iteratively passed Series that includes all the values in each of the groupby'd groups. In this case that function is a lambda function which leverages the size of that passed Series to build a correspondingly sized list that includes a 1 in the first position and 0's in the remaining positions.